# Classify the singularity points of $f(z)=\frac{z}{1-e^{z^2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

I need to find the singularity points of the following function: $$f(z)=\frac{z}{1-e^{z^2}}$$

and determine whether it is a removeable singularity/a pole/an essential singularity, and find the residue.

I know the point $0$ is a singularity, but I'm not sure how to find the function's
Laurent series, or how to determine whether $\;\lim\limits_{z \to 0} \frac{z}{1-e^{z^2}}\;$  exists. I'm pretty new at the subject of singularity points and only did basic examples.

Comment: As $z \to 0$, one gets
$$
f(z)=\frac{z}{1-e^{z^2}}=\frac{z}{1-(1+z^2+\frac{z^3}2+O(z^4))}=-\frac1z+\frac{z}2+O(z^3).
$$

Answer (score 0):

The zeros of $e^z-1$ are of order $1$ at $z \in 2i \pi \mathbb{Z}$,

thus the poles of $\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ are of order $1$ at $z \in 2i \pi \mathbb{Z}$

the poles of $\frac{z}{e^z-1}$ are of order $1$ at $z \in 2i \pi n, n \ne 0$

the poles of $\frac{z^2}{1-e^{z^2}}$  are of order $1$ at $z^2 = 2i \pi n,n \ne 0$ so $z = i^m (1+i) \sqrt{ \pi n},n > 0$

and the poles of $\frac{z}{1-e^{z^2}}$  are of order $1$ at  $z = i^m (1+i) \sqrt{ \pi n}, n \ge 0$

$$ $$

therefore the Cauchy integral formula shows $\frac{z}{1-e^{z^2}}$ has a Laurent series converging for $0 < |z| <  \sqrt{2\pi}$, and another one different for each $n$ converging  for $ \sqrt{2 n\pi} < |z|  < \sqrt{2(n+1)\pi}$

the Taylor series of $\frac{z}{e^z-1}$ is given by the Bernoulli numbers and $\frac{z}{e^z-1}+\frac{z}{2}$ is even means $B_{2k+3} = 0$

Answer (score 0):

There is a lemma which says the following:

An analytic function, $f(z)$ has zeros of order $n$ at $z_{0}$ if $f(z_{0})=f'(z_{0})...=f^{n-1}(z_{0})=0$ and $f^{n}(z_{0}) \neq0$.

Simply put, $f(z_{0})=0$ and $n$ is the first positive integer such that $f^{n}(z_{0}) \neq0$.

In your question, we first let $p(z)=z$ and $q(z)=1-e^{z^{2}}$. The zeros are obtained when we set $$1-e^{z^{2}}=0.$$
Clearly, $z=0$ is a zero of order 1.

Now, we consider $p(z_{0}) =p(0)=z|_{z_{0}=0}=0$.

Finally, $p'(z_{0})=1 \neq 0$. By the lemma, $p(z)$ has a zero, $z=0$ of order 1.

Thus, we conclude that $f(z)$ has a zero, $z=0$ of order $1-1=0$.

That is, $z=0$ is a removable singularity.

Answer (score 0):

Singularites of a [meromorphic function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeromorphicFunction.html) $f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$ are the zeros of the denominator, that is the solution set of the equation $h(z)=0$.

For $f(z)=\frac{z}{e^{z^2}-1}$, the singularities are found as
$$e^{z^2}-1=0\implies \color{red}{z=\pm\sqrt{\pi n}(1\pm i)}$$
where $n\in\Bbb N$.

At $z=0$, it has the Laurent series
$$\frac{z}{e^{z^2}-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{B_k}{k!}z^{2k-1}$$
where $B_k$ is the $k$-th Bernouilli number. So, $z=0$ is a pole of order 1.

Other singularities are also poles of order $1$.